# How to export Highchart with large number of legends

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using Highchart for drawing javascript chart. I am using phantomjs for exporting the chart. But in image when number of legends become very large then at image all the legends does not show (legends with scroll symbol show). I just want to show all the legends at right side of the chart, not scroll symbol at the end. How can I do this.

Comment: See example from here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.align

Comment: yes but that I have already done to align legends in right, I just want to show all the legends in export if number of legends are more then the chart hight

Comment: Check before exporting if you have enough space for legend, if not set higher height for an exported chart. There is nothing built-in for that.